# Need to execute only one HTTP operation in AFNetworking and cancel the previous one

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use the `AFNetworking` framework and need to implement this logic to my web requests:

- only one request is executing;
- if the new request is ready I need to cancel the previous one and execute the new one.

I see that `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is a `NSOperation` subclass, so I can write my own request manager but as I see there is `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` in the framework. I only found that I can make a concurrency queue here so my requests will be executed one after another. Can I get the described behavior with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with [manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations]; ? So if you have existing one, cancel all operations and create new one?

Comment: @NickCatib I have several different requests, executing now, but I need to cancel the one that was executing to specific url/method.. etc

Comment: okay, how about this: save request in the class property, set it to null if it completes, and in the start check if there is existing one. If there is, you can call [request cancel] for that particular one, if not proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put this as an answer as well. So the idea is to do the following:

-create property for AFNetworkingOperation:

```
@property AFHTTPRequestOperation *post;
```

-in your initializer:

```
self.post = nil;
```

-in your function where you call request:

```
if(self.post){
    [post cancel];
}
```

-you need to assign self.post later:

```
self.post = [manager POST:nil parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  self.post = nil;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   // error handling.
}];
```